# How do I run a Ruby script in the Terminal?

Tags: ruby, xml, macos, terminal

I'm attempting to run a Ruby script (linked below) that was shared by DHH to convert a number of .dcp Leica Q camera profiles to Leica M10 camera profiles.

I'm just not sure how to run it. I understand it needs to be run in Terminal but that's about it.

I have all Leica Q camera profiles in a single folder on the desktop... Now what?

I've downloaded the [DCP tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcptool/) that's mentioned in the comments of the script.

Here's a link to the GitHub repo: https://gist.github.com/dhh/d3c8cf9309b662047257b7e583c3f595#file-dcp-converter-rb-L8

I know this might be pretty basic but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the actual script:

````
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Requires that you have ./bin/dcpTool from https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcptool/

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'nokogiri'

input_camera_model  = ARGV[0] || "LEICA Q (Typ 116)"
output_camera_model = ARGV[1] || "LEICA M10"

input_dir  = ARGV[2] || "./input"
output_dir = ARGV[3] || "./output"

def convert_profile_name(profile_name, input_camera_model, output_camera_model)
  File.basename(profile_name.gsub(/#{input_camera_model.gsub(/\(/, "\\(").gsub(/\)/, "\\)")}/, output_camera_model), ".dcp")
end

def replace_camera_model(xml_profile_filename, output_camera_model)
  profile_doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(xml_profile_filename))
  profile_doc.xpath('//UniqueCameraModelRestriction').first.content = output_camera_model  

  File.open(xml_profile_filename, "w+") { |file| file.write(profile_doc.to_xml) }
end

Dir.entries(input_dir).reject { |file| file =~ /^(\.|\.\.)$/ }.each do |existing_profile|
  converted_profile = convert_profile_name(existing_profile, input_camera_model, output_camera_model)
  existing_dcp_filename  = File.join(input_dir, existing_profile)
  xml_filename = "#{File.join(output_dir, converted_profile)}.xml"

  decompile_command = "./bin/dcpTool -d '#{existing_dcp_filename}' '#{xml_filename}'"

  puts "Decompiling #{existing_dcp_filename} into XML"
  `#{decompile_command}`

  puts "Replacing camera model: #{input_camera_model} -> #{output_camera_model}"
  replace_camera_model(xml_filename, output_camera_model)


  converted_dcp_filename = "#{File.join(output_dir, converted_profile)}.dcp"
  recompile_command = "./bin/dcpTool -c '#{xml_filename}' '#{converted_dcp_filename}'"

  puts "Recompiling XML into #{converted_dcp_filename}"
  `#{recompile_command}`

  File.delete(xml_filename)

  puts
end```
````

Comment: @engineersmnky that sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

- Create an "input" and an "output" directory in the same location as this script.
- Place all of your files in "input"
- In the terminal navigate to this location
- type `ruby dcp-converter.rb`.

**Note:** You may have to run `gem install bundler nokogiri` first.

If you have a different model than the one shown you may have to pass additional arguments e.g. `ruby dcp-converter.rb "LEICA Q (Typ 202)"`

The argument order would be `ruby dcp-converter.rb [input_model] [output_model] [input_directory] [output_directory]`

The defaults are

- [input_model] = "LEICA Q (Typ 116)"
- [output_model]="LEICA M10"
- [input_directory]="./input"
- [output_directory]="./output"